# iOS table view don't start with first row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I do everything in tutorial but row don't start in first row

[Table View in Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Oat.png)

[Code for table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtDeq.png)

Comment: select your view controller in storyboard -> attribute inspector -> uncheck adjust scrollview insets

Comment: some time it happens remove your tableView from your view controller in storyboard then again add tableView in  view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to fix this:

First Solution: **select your view controller in storyboard -> attribute inspector -> uncheck adjust scrollview insets**

Second Solution:
**set top constraint of tableView to the superView = 0 instead of TopLayoutGuide = 0**

Comment: Thanks 1st one is perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
    // stop auto scroll for the table
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Write this line of code to ViewWillApear() in ViewController class